# Why is my Aloe losing leaves?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, diseases, succulents, aloe

I’ve had this plant since August and recently it has lost a couple of leaves, I was wondering if anyone could identify a cause. Thanks [image]

Comment: Another picture of the plant would help

Comment: @kevinsky The main plant looks like any other aloe Vera as far as I’m aware, the bottom leaf is droopy but they’re all a darkish healthy green